# How to list, create and delete Google Compute instances?

Tags: php, google-compute-engine

Could someone please show me some code examples or link to some up to date examples of how to use the PHP Google Compute API to list, create and delete Google Compute instances? I can't find any full up to date examples in PHP anywhere. Google's only seem to be partial and Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can find code samples for PHP (and other language) in the API documentation, e.g.,

- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/start#examples
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/get#examples
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/list#examples

For PHP specifically, see also [GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples) GitHub project which uses the [Google API PHP Client PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). Here's [more info](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries#google_apis_php_client_library) on how to install and use the PHP client library.

Comment: thats 3 years out of date, in the end i just did it all using gcloud commandline :-)

Comment: @jamie — sorry about that and good catch. We'll get that fixed ASAP. Glad you were able to use `gcloud` as an alternative.

Comment: The documentation on site is even completely outdated, no idea if that thing still works at all.
Really a shame how hard Google makes it for developers in comparison to AWS.

Comment: @John – can you please be more specific about which page or code sample was out of date? If it's a GitHub repo, you can file an issue, if it's a doc, you can submit feedback (we read and fix the issues), or just point me at the specific URL and I'll file it on your behalf. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your app.php link is dead, the current one is here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/compute/helloworld

Readme starts with requirements: a google library URL that is dead
Followed with authentication steps that are deprecated
The stuff is not even found anymore on the Google compute website.

The example itself didn't run as well for me but it was helpful to learn a bit about the API.

Instead of having one huge example.php you'd need a set of short, simple files that simply work. "list-instances.php" "create-snapshot.php" etc.
20 lines of code e

Comment: @John – thanks for the details! I updated the link in my post (you can also submit edits to answers); I proposed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/pull/526 to fix the git repo URL; filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/527 to update auth setup; and also filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/528 to split / simplify the code samples. Feel free to subscribe to the issues to follow up on their status updates. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Sounds good.
One general thing I was stuck with is quite simple:
I start an instance, I receive a status response from the API.

How do I know if it was successful ? 
Should I look if the error object is filled, does it always mean it was a success?
Should I look for status=PENDING ? Is that the only status possible on success?

I tried to find anything like that in the documentation and I could not even find the different STATUS strings.
There is no documentation, at least not on obvious places or where google finds it, that describes such basics.

That makes learning it anoying

Comment: @John — I've updated my answer to include short code samples for the different APIs, take a look. Re: status when creating: see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances#resource, the status options are: PROVISIONING, STAGING, RUNNING, STOPPING, STOPPED, SUSPENDING, SUSPENDED, and TERMINATED.

Comment: Looks great, thanks. I've corrected a typo, the link was probably supposed to mean "start" not "create".
The examples are way better, have they always been there ?

Comment: @John — thanks for fixing the typo! The examples have been there for some time but I don't know exactly how long. I was informed about them in response to one of my bugs I filed on GitHub where a decision was made to remove the "helloworld" example as the examples in the API docs are already better, and in all languages. Does this address all your questions / use cases or did you need anything else?

Comment: Update:  based on my [earlier-filed GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/528#issue-285725121), new GCE API examples are in the works in [this PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php/pull/208).